# Access kubernetes web ui from remote computer

Tags: kubernetes

I installed Web UI for kubernetes on master node. I am using Ubuntu Server 18.04.2. Following [this tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) and it states that you must access dashboard from localhost. I need to access it from remote PC.

UPDATE:
I executed a dashboard with following command:

kubectl proxy --accept-hosts='.*' --address='100.180.3.11'

100.180.3.11 is external machine IP. I am able to get to sign in page. When I provide a token, nothing happens. Hint: seems like a cookie is not written and not being redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly.

Once you have deployed the dashboard as mentioned in the article for example, connect to your cluster from your machine or remote station (the command to connect depends on your cloud provider).

Once you are connected to the cluster, try to execute "kubectl proxy" (do not stop the running kubectl proxy command), then try to surf to the url.

Comment: The problem is that the command should be executed on the master node and then you need to access it with localhost. I don't have option to connect with localhost since it is a server machine without UI installed

Comment: You can execute the command from your home computer as long as the kubectl has access to the master (usually port 6443) than you can access the kubernetes web ui on your localhost

Answer (score 0):

Set dashboard service type to nodeport. You should be able to access the dashboard from other computers

Comment: Are there any references / examples on how to do so?

Comment: deploy dashboard from this link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/epasham/docker-repo/master/k8s/dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard.yml

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you your cluster is on VM's in bridged mode or that you can just access the node's IP from remote machine in the same network you can just change the type of service to NodePort and then access the dashboard on your node IP and access it on `https://NODEIP:PORT`.

Probably the reason that nothing happens after you add the token is the fact that you are using `kubectl proxy` which only allows HTTP connections. You won't be able to access it from any other place than localhost address. More information [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above#kubectl-proxy).